# Unlimited subway card Paris

Tags: public-transport, paris

I will soon be going to Paris for two weeks to improve my French. I will have to make one specific subway journey along one specific line (from my accommodation to the school and back) every day, and would also like to have the ability to move about the city a bit outside of that. What would be the best/most cost-effective public transport pass/card to accomplish this?

If at all practical I'd prefer an option where I can travel as much as I want during my time there for a flat fee (rather than pay per ride) because I'd find that a more relaxing way to travel (so I can just travel as much as I want without worrying that *this* trip or *that* plan is specifically costing me), but if such an option does not exist or is unreasonably expensive I would of course consider a pay per ride option.

(I'm 23 years old and an EU citizen, in case it's relevant.)

EDIT: the school is [ACCORD École de Langues](http://www.accord-langues.com/) at 14 Boulevard Poissonnière, and my accomodation is quite a bit away from there, near the Parc de Bercy. I will be arriving on Sunday July 7 and leaving on Saturday July 20.

Comment: Where are the accommodation and school? What day of the week will you be arriving and departing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most obvious choice is to use a Navigo weekly or monthly pass.

A Navigo weekly pass covering all 5 zones (the whole Ile-de-France region) is 22.80 and is valid Monday to Sunday.

A Navigo monthly pass is 75.20, so that would probably only be worth it if you stay more than 2 weeks and start before a Monday and end after a Sunday.

Add to that 5 euros for the Navigo Découverte smart card on which you will load either pass.

This will allow travel on all metro, RER, bus, trams and commuter trains in the region.

There is a student pass (Imagine R) but I believe it is only available on a yearly basis.

Comment: I was just reviewing some of my old Stack Exchange questions and answers and noticed that I had forgotten to accept this answer last year. I followed your advice and it worked perfectly. Most other students I spoke to had also done the same, suggesting that there was no obvious superior alternative available.